# Getting time format with milliseconds for the locale

Tags: java, localization, date-formatting

I'm working on localizing an existing Java app, part of which involves replacing lines like

```
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
```

with

```
DateFormat f2 = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
```

All well and good. But now I need to localize the following:

```
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss.SSS a");
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Searches are failing me. I could always cast to SimpleDateFormat, grab the pattern, and replace `ss` with `ss.SSS`, but I'd much rather use a method that is less likely to break in the future.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I can think of two options -

1. Define a constant of your own
2. Make your own enum

```
public static String MY_DATE_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss.SSS a"; // a constant.
public static enum DATE_FORMATS { // a enum
  SHORT, LONG, MEDIUM;
  public String toString() {
    switch (this) {
    case SHORT:
      return "HH:mm:ss"; // this should be loaded from a ResourceBundle.
    case LONG:
      return "HH:mm:ss.SSS a";  // this should be loaded from a ResourceBundle.
    case MEDIUM:
      return "HH:mm:ss.SSS";  // this should be loaded from a ResourceBundle.
    }
    return "";
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(MY_DATE_FORMAT); // option 1
  System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMATS.SHORT.toString()); // option 2
  System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
}
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand how this handles the localization. Seems like any time I call
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMATS.SHORT.toString()); 
I'll get a time with am/pm, whether that's appropriate or not.

Comment: Sorry, you then load the actual formats out of a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).